# Data Points Subtraction

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a table of data points to be subtracted by another table of data points. I have succeed in subtracting the y values of each data point successfully, but it is the x values of each data point in that I have trouble.

```
m = 10;
DataList = Table[{}, {i, 1, m}];
BGData = Import["BatchData-Background.txt", "Table"];
BGPlot = ListPlot[BGData, FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Voltage [V]"}, PlotStyle -> Black] 

Do[{DataList[[i]] = Import["BatchData-B" <> ToString[i] <> "V.txt", "Table"];
DataPlot = ListPlot[DataList[[i]], FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Voltage (V)"}, PlotStyle -> Gray]; Print["B = ", i, "Volts"]; Print[DataPlot];}, {i, 1, m}];

m = 10;
SubDataList = Table[{DataList[[i, All, 2]] - BGData[[All, 2]]}, {i, 1, m}]; 

Do[{SubDataPlot = ListPlot[SubDataList[[i]]];}, {i, 1, m}] `

m = 10;
SubDataList = Table[{DataList[[i,All,2]]-BGData[[All,2]]},{i,1,m}];
Do[{SubDataPlot=ListPlot[SubDataList[[i]]];},{i,1,m}]
```

This is the code that I am having trouble with. However, my plot will get y values correct, but my x-axis is automatically set to `0` to `1400` in steps of `200`. However, my data points shows that my x-axis should be from `0` to `0.07` in steps of `0.01`.

Both `DataList` and `BGData` are table of its own and the specifications that I have done for each just extracts the `y-values` in each table and subtracts them.

Answer (score 0):

Read a bit more of the documentation of `ListPlot`.  The expression

```
ListPlot[SubDataList]
```

plots, as you observe, the values in `SubDataList` from `1` to `m`.  If you supply a second list of values to the function, perhaps

```
ListPlot[{SubDataList, BGData}]
```

treats the first list as a list of *x*-coordinates and the second as a list of *y*-coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Making some example data points for `subDataList` from 0 to 1400 and plotting them on an x-scale from 0 to 0.07:-

```
subDataList = Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/1400}];

ListPlot[Transpose[{Prepend[Range[1400]*0.00005, 0], subDataList}]]
```

[image]